# Powershell script as a step in sql job giving error

Tags: sql, powershell, sql-server-2012, sql-job

I am trying to create a sql job which syncs users from a csv file to ad group.
My powershell script is one of the steps of this job. Issue is that my script is supposed to run on another server which has Active Directory but i keep on getting error when i run this step.

My script is following:

```
invoke-Command -Session Server-Name
Import-Module activedirectory
$ADUsers = Import-csv \\Server-Name\folder\file.csv
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{  
    $Username = $User.sAMAccountName
   $group=$user.adgroup 

if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
{
 foreach($group in $groups){Add-ADGroupMember -identity $group -Members $Username}

    Write-Output "$username has beeen added to group $group"

  }
}
```

Error i am getting is

> Executed as user: Username. A job step received an error at line 2 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'Invoke-Command -Session Server-Name. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Cannot bind parameter 'Session'. Cannot convert the "Server-Name" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession".  '.  Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed.

server name has '-' in between so need to know if that is causing the issue
or i am using wrong way to run this script on a different server from a sql job

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sql job for AD sync seems strange an idea. Why's that?

Comment: A step before this one creates an export of csv file containing emails and groups from database. I want  whole of this process to automate. thats why i am creating this sync

Comment: Did you check the [help for Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6)?  The error message is giving you a clue as to what is wrong:  You are trying to pass a server name where it expects a session object.  Either create a session first (with `New-PSSession`) or use the `-ComputerName` parameter rather than the `-Session` one.  Also, you need to wrap the code you want to run on the remote server in a scriptblock: `{...}` as part of `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: @boxdog Thanks a lot it worked.

Comment: @boxdog .... Your comment helped me when things were getting twisted up running that within a function and after finding this comment and reading it, ding, ding, ding, that fixed it for me too... Du'oh.... the session name, not the server name.... wow.... Tag me back if you write this up as an answer so I can up vote it and I assume the OP will accept since his comment states it resolved that problem too.

Answer (score 2):

Jaspreet I am not expert on powershell but seems like you are passing the wrong parameters.Just referring to Microsoft docs seems like you need to pass the computer name rather than -Session
Try with this line of code at starting
invoke-Command -ComputerName Server-Name.
For more please refer Microsoft docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6#examples